# swift Casting generic sub class to its supper class

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Here is my code

```
class Chair{}
class MyChair:Chair {}

class House<T:Chair> {
}

class MyHouse<D:MyChair>:House<MyChair>{}
```

Now if i try the following

```
var houseClass:AnyObject = MyHouse<MyChair>.self
println(houseClass is House<Chair>.Type)  // return false
println(houseClass is House<MyChair>.Type)  // return true
```

Does any one know the reason for this?

Comment: Which version of Swift is this? `println` belongs to 1.x.